# MX Record warning causing emails to not be sent?

Tags: postfix, mx-record

Is it possible the following error could cause emails to not be sent?

```
 warning: numeric domain name in resource data of MX record for domain.com: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Our customer support department says there' been a huge spike in customers not receiving RMA emails.  No code on the RMA site has changed at all, we haven't updated the production server.  I'm showing about a 97% success rate on emails being sent from the server logs.

Any ideas on what I should look at to determine the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An MX record should be a fully qualified domain name, not an IP address. Most clients will send to an IP address, but some won't. It's a simple fix, why take the risk? Just make sure you have a corresponding A record.